# how make fast loading speed of embedded youtube VIDEO and woff file

Tags: html, css, youtube

My code use this code

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vodID" title="VOD" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and this code

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'font name';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;

src: url(./fonts/file location) format('woff2'),
url(./fonts/file location) format('woff'),
url(./fonts/file location) format('opentype');}
```

this code spend long loading time(in webpagetest.org)

How can I improve it?

Comment: I m not sure if i follow but i think that loading speed is a matter of user network.

Comment: Where's the `Javascript`, `PHP` or `jquery` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does webpagetest say?

You can add prefetch for youtube to help. This is a great article about meta pre-stuff [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/).

`<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//example.com">`

Regarding the font (i'm not sure about your knowlege here) but maybe you have the "wrong settings for it meaning you included other characters that you don't need. Depending on the license you can take the font and clean it from unnecessary characters, but this is nerding you actually don't have to do this.

[image]